# Using powershell can we do automation script to auto restart the azure vm agent if the agent is not responding?

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine

1) Verify Azure VM agent Status 
2) IF status good, not require to restart agent. IF staus dellocated, require to restart agent.

Comment: What do you mean `not good`? VM deallocated?

Comment: yes dellocated .....

Answer (score 0):

You should start by first detecting if the VM agent is installed or not:

```
Get-AzVM
```

Result:

```
OSProfile                  :
  ComputerName             : myVM
  AdminUsername            : myUserName
  WindowsConfiguration     :
    ProvisionVMAgent       : True
    EnableAutomaticUpdates : True
```

The Azure VM agent might be stopped, outdated, in an inconsistent state, or not installed and prevent Azure Backup service to trigger snapshots.

1. If the VM agent is stopped or is in an inconsistent state, Restart
   the Agent and retry the backup operation (try an ad-hoc backup). For
   steps to restart the agent, see [Windows VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/backup/backup-azure-troubleshoot-vm-backup-fails-snapshot-timeout#the-agent-installed-in-the-vm-but-unresponsive-for-windows-vms) or [Linux VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-machines/linux/update-agent).
2. If the VM agent is not installed or is outdated, install/update the
   VM agent and retry the backup operation. For steps to install/update
   the agent, see [Windows VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows) or [Linux VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-machines/linux/update-agent).

In order to run a process on Linux, follow below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command

Windows:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command

---

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows#detect-the-vm-agent

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-troubleshoot-vm-backup-fails-snapshot-timeout#UserErrorGuestAgentStatusUnavailable-vm-agent-unable-to-communicate-with-azure-backup